# Elastic API custom date field range query

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I'm learning Elasticsearch API while practicing I'm facing the issue is unable to fetch documents between two dates those documents match two fields but without date range it's working fine

```
    BoolQueryBuilder filter = new BoolQueryBuilder();
    BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

    for (String q : list) {
            // both the fields must exists
            query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field1", q))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field2", val));
            filter.should(query);
    }

    filter.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("datetime").gte(from).lte(to);

    searchSourceBuilder.query(filter);
```

Where,

`list` contains the list of words for the `field1` field.
Both `field1` & `field2` must match such document I want to retrieve

`datetime` is a custom datetime field & the value looks like `2022-06-09 12:32:36`

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: JHLRC is deprecated if you are using Elasticsearch > 7.15 you should use their latest client https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html

Comment: @Amit yes I'm using 8.2 latest version

Answer (score 0):

I think you need, Date format to convert date values in the query. To format your dates, either use the built-in formats provided by ES - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

or, you can try customised format - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

After formatting, gte and lte should work as expected.